# Cannot Install Kivy - MAC OS 10.11.6

Tags: kivy

Every time I try to install kivy on my MAC-OS I get this error.

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/y9/jt_3161d5wq2gntpvh9hq62c0000gp/T/pip-install-hw1k89ak/kivy/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/y9/jt_3161d5wq2gntpvh9hq62c0000gp/T/pip-install-hw1k89ak/kivy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/y9/jt_3161d5wq2gntpvh9hq62c0000gp/T/pip-pip-egg-info-n2hhez9l
         cwd: /private/var/folders/y9/jt_3161d5wq2gntpvh9hq62c0000gp/T/pip-install-hw1k89ak/kivy/
    Complete output (91 lines):
    fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/y9/jt_3161d5wq2gntpvh9hq62c0000gp/T/pip-wheel-za11bzp2/cython/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/y9/jt_3161d5wq2gntpvh9hq62c0000gp/T/pip-wheel-za11bzp2/cython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/y9/jt_3161d5wq2gntpvh9hq62c0000gp/T/pip-wheel-jqs2qwkh
           cwd: /private/var/folders/y9/jt_3161d5wq2gntpvh9hq62c0000gp/T/pip-wheel-za11bzp2/cython/
      Complete output (7 lines):
      Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help

```
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cython
ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
 WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
     subprocess.check_call(cmd)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
 subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/var/folders/y9/jt_3161d5wq2gntpvh9hq62c0000gp/T/tmp69rb6fr7', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/private/var/folders/y9/jt_3161d5wq2gntpvh9hq62c0000gp/T/pip-install-hw1k89ak/kivy/setup.py", line 1073, in <module>
     setup(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 160, in setup
     _install_setup_requires(attrs)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 155, in _install_setup_requires
     dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 695, in fetch_build_eggs
     resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 781, in resolve
     dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1066, in best_match
     return self.obtain(req, installer)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1078, in obtain
     return installer(requirement)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 754, in fetch_build_egg
     return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
     raise DistutilsError(str(e))
 distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/var/folders/y9/jt_3161d5wq2gntpvh9hq62c0000gp/T/tmp69rb6fr7', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Using setuptools
User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
Using this graphics system: OpenGL ES 2
OSX framework used, force to x86_64 only
OSX ARCHFLAGS are: -arch x86_64
GStreamer framework not found, fallback on pkg-config
WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 127)

b'/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found\n'

Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework
Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework
Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework
Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_mixer.framework
SDL2 frameworks not found, fallback on pkg-config
WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 127)

b'/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found\n'

Xcode detected at b'/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools', and using OS X10.11 sdk
WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags pangoft2 (code 127)

b'/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found\n'

ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone helped me out with this error and help me resolve this issue. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. It worked when I tried:

```
    $ python -m pip install kivy==2.0.0rc1
```

I hope it works !